# Racket - Function for tracing factorial

Tags: recursion, racket

I am a beginner at racket and am working on a recursive procedure. Now I have a recursive procedure called 'factorial' that gives me the end result.

Now I am trying to make a second recursive procedure that is supposed to give me the steps resulting to the end result and put them in a list. And I'd like to make use of my 'factorial' procedure.

```
(define factorial (lambda (n) (cond [(equal? n 1) (cons 1 null)]
                                    [(> n 1) (* n (factorial(- n 1)))])))


(define factorialSteps (lambda (n) (cond [(equal? n 1) 1]
                                         [(> n 1) (cons (factorial n) (factorialSteps(- n 1)))])))
```

What I'd like to happen:
(factorial 5) = 120

(factorialSteps 5) = '(1 2 6 24 120)

What happens: (factorialSteps 5) = '(120 24 6 2 1)

Comment: You do `(cons (factorial 5) (factorialSteps 4))`, which is backwards. You need to either build the list in the opposite order or reverse it when you're done. (Also, that doesn't happen at all - it tries to multiply a number with a list. `factorialSteps` should produce a list in both cases, `factorial` should never produce a list.)